# Automating a step-by-step process from an MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

We use SOLR for autocomplete search in our web application. We have a nightly process that adds a bunch of data to our database, and once that process finishes, we need to import that data from the database into our SOLR server.

Currently that import process is done manually in the following sequence:

1. Check if ondeck SOLR server is idle
2. Tell ondeck server to do a full import of the data, server status is "busy"
3. Poll ondeck server every so often and when it finishes, the status reverts to idle.
4. Swap the ondeck server (with the new information) with the live SOLR server.
5. Run a stored procedure on our database.

We have an administrative tools page on our web app. What I want to do is put a button on that page that kicks off that process (via AJAX call to our web application) and tells the user that the process has been kicked off. The entire process takes about an hour to do so I can't have the AJAX call run for an hour and then get back to the page telling the user that the process is finished.

I need it done asynchronously. The process has to be kicked off, once it gets kicked off, it informs the user that it's begun, and then the application has continue waiting on each step of the process and then call the next step until it finishes. What does the code in MVC 4 look like to make this happen? I've been looking at the tutorials on MSDN on `async` and `await` but I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest you to take a look on Websokets (or long poling if you have to support old browsers). There is a really nice library called [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) which will handle all complex staff for you. It use websockets if it is supported by client browser or automatically switch to long poling if it's not. It has good [documentation](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Persistent-Connections) and a lot of expamles on the Internet.